# Terminal line wrapping issues with Python 3.5

Tags: bash, python-3.x, miniconda

When using Python 3.x -based conda environments I am experiencing problems with wrapping of long commands in the IPython terminal:

[image: screenshot_2016-06-21_15-58-08]

In this case I was trying to scroll back left along a previous command in order to edit it. Scrolling along the line triggered this observed behaviour where the line replicated several times, garbling the line contents as it did so.

This happens with every command that I try to edit which exceeds the width of the window.

This behaviour does not occur when I use a conda environment with Python 2.7.

This behaviour occurs even when I start a new terminal with empty .bashrc and .bash_profile files (which removes my user-made PS1 modifications that I've seen cause problems elsewhere). The `env` command outputs:

```
XDG_VTNR=7
SSH_AGENT_PID=1309
XDG_SESSION_ID=1
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID=2150
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-
QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON=1
MRT_DATA_DIR=/home/user/MRT//data
GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
USER=at15963
QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
DESKTOP_AUTOSTART_ID=106d6eb4d9d46fcd27146651600338280400000011880001
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
MRT_HOME=/home/at15963/MRT/
SESSION_MANAGER=local/vbox:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1188,unix/vbox:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1188
USERNAME=user
DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/gnome.default.path
GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE=/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-settings-daemon.desktop
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-gnome:/etc/xdg
PATH=/home/at15963/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/user/MRT//bin
DESKTOP_SESSION=gnome
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
PWD=/home/at15963
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/gnome.mandatory.path
NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript
GDMSESSION=gnome
XDG_SEAT=seat0
HOME=/home/user
SHLVL=1
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=gnome
LOGNAME=user
QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-CWQedsdWnh,guid=062ea6ffba5dd776e8e9b7e45769421e
WINDOWPATH=7
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
DISPLAY=:0
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Conda specs for environment:

```
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
# $ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
# platform: linux-64
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size=1.0.0=py35_0
cycler=0.10.0=py35_0
decorator=4.0.10=py35_0
fontconfig=2.11.1=2
freetype=2.6.3=0
icu=56.1=2
ipython=4.2.0=py35_1
ipython_genutils=0.1.0=py35_0
libiconv=1.14=2
libpng=1.6.22=0
libxml2=2.9.3=8
matplotlib=1.5.1=np111py35_2
mkl=11.3.3=0
ncurses=5.9=7
numpy=1.11.0=py35_1
openssl=1.0.2h=1
pexpect=4.1.0=py35_0
pickleshare=0.7.2=py35_0
pip=8.1.2=py35_0
ptyprocess=0.5.1=py35_0
pyparsing=2.1.4=py35_0
pyqt=4.11.4=py35_3
python=3.5.1=0
python-dateutil=2.5.3=py35_0
python-simplegeneric=0.8.1=py35_0
pytz=2016.4=py35_0
qt=4.8.7=3
readline=6.2=2
setuptools=23.0.0=py35_0
sip=4.18=py35_0
six=1.10.0=py35_0
sqlite=3.9.2=0
tk=8.5.19=0
traitlets=4.2.1=py35_0
wheel=0.29.0=py35_0
xz=5.0.5=1
zlib=1.2.8=3
```

I'm running Ubuntu GNOME with LXTerminal but this behaviour also occurs in XTerm and MATE Terminal.

On the other hand, I know that line wrapping with the same conda environment behaves properly on a remote server that I access over SSH - the line wraps around to a second, third line of the terminal etc, rather than outputting the < and > characters.  `env` on this server (some values masked out):

```
XDG_SESSION_ID=49854
HOSTNAME=(masked)
SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED=
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
HISTSIZE=1000
SSH_CLIENT=(masked)
SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE=
QTDIR=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3
QTINC=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/include
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/16
QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM_CHECKED=1
USER=(masked)
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/(masked)
PATH=/home/(masked)/miniconda3/envs/py35/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
PWD=/home/(masked)
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
MODULEPATH=/opt/modulefiles:/usr/share/Modules/modulefiles:/etc/modulefiles
LOADEDMODULES=
PS1=(py35)\n\[\e[90m\]╔[\[\e[36m\]\u\[\e[90m\]@\[\e[32m\]\h: \[\e[93;1m\]\w\[\e[90m\]]\n╚>\[\e[m\]$ 
SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED=
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/(masked)
CONDA_ENV_PATH=/home/(masked)/miniconda3/envs/py35
LOGNAME=(masked)
QTLIB=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/lib
SSH_CONNECTION=(masked)
MODULESHOME=/usr/share/Modules
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=py35
LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/305828
DISPLAY=localhost:23.0
BASH_FUNC_module()=() {  eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd bash $*`
}
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Any ideas on what's going on would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I checked over a few more dependencies in depth and eventually found the root(s) of the problem - conflicting `readlines`, `curses` and `backports.shutil_get_terminal_size` packages. These had resulted from having the `conda-forge` channel active. Turning the channel off, removing the above packages and then installing Py3.5 and iPython again did the trick.

So looks like bleeding-edge packages in conda-forge were to blame.